AM-GM-type inequality for probability measures without $n$-th root?
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal F$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i)\quad?
\end{equation}
For $n=2$ this follows fairly straightforward from the monotonicity of the probability measure and the inclusion-exclusion-principle. For the general case I tried a similar approach (Bonferroni inequalities) and induction; both without success.
Any help/counter example is appreciated.
Edit 1: Removed exponent $\frac{1}{n}$ on the LHS of the equation
Edit 2: Proof for n=2
By monotonicity of $\mathbb P$ and the inclusion exclusion principle we get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2) \leq \mathbb P(A_1\cup A_2) = \mathbb P(A_1) + \mathbb P(A_2) - \mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2).
\end{equation}
Rearranging yields
\begin{equation}
2\cdot\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2) \leq \mathbb P(A_1) + \mathbb P(A_2)
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2) \leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\mathbb P(A_1) + \mathbb P(A_2)).
\end{equation}

False for $n=2$, in fact for any $n >1$. Take $A_i$ independent of $i$.

I added the proof for $n=2$. Could you point me to my mistake? And do you have a specific counterexample for larger $n$?

@geetha290krm: Sorry, I didn't mean to put the $n$-th root on the LHS.

$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \min_{1\leq i \leq n} P(A_i)  \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i)$.

We have:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\biggl( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i \biggr)
&= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{A_i} \biggr] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \biggl( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{A_i} \biggr)^{1/n} \biggr] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{A_i} \biggr] \tag{$\because$ AM-GM}\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}(A_i)
\end{align*}
